# How to Remove or overwrite sonata admin pagination?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

When creating a page, pagination takes a very long time. I want to delete it or override it. Tell me who faced I want to remove these things
[image: check image]

Answer (score 3):

### To remove only the Twig view (no impact on performance, it's just visual) :

you can define a custom Pager using this :

```
# app/config/your_sonata_services_config.yml
services:
    app.admin.post:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\PostAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Post", pager_type: "simple" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - AppBundle\Entity\Post
            - ~
        public: true
```

With tag `pager_type: simple`, the view `SonataAdminBundle:Pager:simple_pager_results.html.twig` will be called.

source : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_improve_performance_large_datasets.html

### To disable COUNT(*) of rows and improve performance :

You can have a look here https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/issues/297, you have to :

1. extend the default `SonataPager` with your own class that overrides `computeNbResult()`
2. extends the default `SonataProxyQuery` with your own class that overrides `getFixedQueryBuilder()`
3. extend the default `SonataDatagridBuilder` with your own class that overrides `getBaseDatagrid()`
4. Reference those in your services